# Does the inner pentagon inside a Robbins pentagon $also$ have a rational area?

Tags: triangles, area, rational-numbers, polygons

The *Heron triangle* has integer sides and area. The *[Robbins pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_pentagon)* is just the generalization: it also has integer sides and area. The example below has sides $78, 126, 66, 50, 32$ and area $A_R = \color{brown}{4392}$.

$\hskip2.0in$[image]

Define the formula for the area of Heron triangles as,

$$A_H(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$$

We can partition the above Robbins pentagon into ***three*** Heron triangles and find that indeed,

$$A_R = A_H(78,126,120) + A_H(32,120,104) + A_H(104,50,66) =  \color{brown}{4392}$$

**P.S.** Notice that the five diagonals form a *pentagram* (a $5$-pointed star) and also form a small pentagon .

> **Question**:

1. For this example, what is the area $A_r$ of the small pentagon?
2. In general, if $A_R$ is rational, then is $A_r$ also rational?

Comment: A related post is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502496/about-the-ratio-of-the-areas-of-a-convex-pentagon-and-the-inner-pentagon-made-by).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place the large pentagon on a coordinate plane such that the vertices are $$\{(0,0), (96/5, -128/5), (336/5, -198/5), (120,0), (96/5, 378/5)\}.$$

Then the coordinates of the small pentagon $p'$ would be $$\left\{\left(\tfrac{3072}{85}, -\tfrac{12672}{595}\right), \left(\tfrac{10893}{190}, -\tfrac{1512}{95}\right), \left(\tfrac{507}{10}, 0\right), \left(\tfrac{96}{5},0\right), \left(\tfrac{96}{5}, -\tfrac{396}{35}\right)\right\}.$$  The resulting area is $$A_r = \frac{6983658}{11305}.$$

but $p'$ is ***not*** a Robbins pentagon.

The answer to your second question is not likely to be known, because it is not yet known whether there exist any Robbins pentagons that have interior diagonals that are irrational, but this is not a rigorous argument by any means.

Comment: Wow, great! But re my comment above, this would imply a family of Robbins pentagons that are getting infinitely smaller, doesn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily.  We do know that if a Robbins pentagon has vertices with rational coordinates, then the intersection of their diagonals will also be rational, but this does not guarantee that the side lengths of the interior pentagon will also be rational.

Comment: A small favor. Can you find the diagonals of the small Robbins pentagon and see if it yields an even smaller Robbins pentagon? Maybe instead it will have irrational diagonals and you'll find the first example.  :)

Comment: That would not help.  The small pentagon is not a Robbins pentagon because although its coordinates are rational, its side lengths are not all rational:  only two of its sides are rational.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. The area $A_r$ is rational, but its sides are not. Dang...